# NSPredicate with relationship @"SELF.<relationship>.<relationship>.<object> == %@"

Tags: core-data, nspredicate, relationship, nsmanagedobject, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have the following `NSManagedObjects`:

```
Product <<->> ProductAttribute <->> ProductAttributeOption
```

What's the correct way for using an NSPredicate to fetch the `ProductAttributeOption`s based on the product?

I've tried the following without luck:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY SELF.productAttribute.products MATCHES %@", product]

[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY SELF.productAttribute@distinctUnionOfSets.products MATCHES %@"", product]

[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY SELF.productAttribute.@distinctUnionOfSets.giftProducts LIKE[cd] %@", self.giftProduct]
```

Any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following predicate should work:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY productAttribute.products = %@", product];
```

"MATCH" and "LIKE" are used in predicates for matching strings.

Comment: Almost there, I ended up with `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY SELF.productAttribute.products = %@", product]` But it led me on the right path :) Thanks!

Comment: @runmad: I would have thought that both versions (with or without `SELF`) work with a fetch request. But anyway, I am glad that it helped.